# Gente, queria agrupar UF do Brasil em regiões no R, já criei uma coluna de dummies pra cada, mas n sei como eu posso agrupá-las em uma só coluna

Tags: r

Ex:
O que eu já fiz é isso:

```
MICRODADOS.ENEM.2020$Norte= ifelse(MICRODADOS.ENEM.2020$SG_UF_PROVA =="RR"
                                   |MICRODADOS.ENEM.2020$SG_UF_PROVA =="AP"
                                   |MICRODADOS.ENEM.2020$SG_UF_PROVA =="PA"
                                   |MICRODADOS.ENEM.2020$SG_UF_PROVA =="AM"
                                   |MICRODADOS.ENEM.2020$SG_UF_PROVA =="AC"
                                   |MICRODADOS.ENEM.2020$SG_UF_PROVA =="RO"
                                   |MICRODADOS.ENEM.2020$SG_UF_PROVA =="TO",1,0)

MICRODADOS.ENEM.2020$Nordeste= ifelse(MICRODADOS.ENEM.2020$SG_UF_PROVA =="MA"
                                   |MICRODADOS.ENEM.2020$SG_UF_PROVA =="PI"
                                   |MICRODADOS.ENEM.2020$SG_UF_PROVA =="CE"
                                   |MICRODADOS.ENEM.2020$SG_UF_PROVA =="RN"
                                   |MICRODADOS.ENEM.2020$SG_UF_PROVA =="PB"
                                   |MICRODADOS.ENEM.2020$SG_UF_PROVA =="PE"
                                   |MICRODADOS.ENEM.2020$SG_UF_PROVA =="AL"
                                   |MICRODADOS.ENEM.2020$SG_UF_PROVA =="SE"
                                   |MICRODADOS.ENEM.2020$SG_UF_PROVA =="BA",1,0)
```

Mas n sei como eu agrupo em uma coluna só as regiões, separados por números
EX:
COLUNA: REGIÃO
Norte: todos os estados detém o número 1
Nordeste: número 2
Sul: número 3 ..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa das variáveis dummie. Pode criar vetores com as siglas das UFs e usar indexação condicional. Como não postou uma amostra dos seus dados, vou usar um exemplo genérico:

```
set.seed(873)
dados <- data.frame(UF = sample(LETTERS[1:8], 16, TRUE))

norte <- LETTERS[1:2]
sul <- LETTERS[3:4]
leste <- LETTERS[5:6]
oeste <- LETTERS[7:8]

dados$regiao[dados$UF %in% norte] <- 1
dados$regiao[dados$UF %in% sul] <- 2
dados$regiao[dados$UF %in% leste] <- 3
dados$regiao[dados$UF %in% oeste] <- 4

head(dados)
#>   UF regiao
#> 1  C      2
#> 2  H      4
#> 3  A      1
#> 4  F      3
#> 5  G      4
#> 6  D      2
```

Se possui uma tabela com as siglas e os códigos (p.e. obtida pelo [SIDRA](https://sidra.ibge.gov.br/territorio)), pode criar um dicionário de substituição:

```
regioes <- data.frame(UF = LETTERS[1:8], cod_reg = rep(1:4, each = 2))

regioes
#>   UF cod_reg
#> 1  A       1
#> 2  B       1
#> 3  C       2
#> 4  D       2
#> 5  E       3
#> 6  F       3
#> 7  G       4
#> 8  H       4

dic.regioes <- setNames(regioes$cod_reg, regioes$UF)

dados$regiao <- dic.regioes[dados$UF]
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode importar ou criar uma tabela com os nomes ou valores que deseja utilizar (UF, região) e depois unir essa tabela com os dados que está processando.

Por exemplo:

### Carregar a tabela com microdados do ENEM 2020

```r
library(data.table)

tb <- fread("../MICRODADOS_ENEM_2020.csv", nrows = 10, select = "SG_UF_PROVA")
```

### Carregando uma tabela com UF, Estado e Região do Brasil

```r
tb2 <- fread("../Estados_Brasil.csv", select = c("UF", "Estado", "Região"))
```

Transformando a Variável "Região" em número e incluindo o dado na coluna "Região2":

```r
tb2[, Região2 := c("Norte" = 1L,
                   "Nordeste" = 2L,
                   "Sudeste" = 3L,
                   "Sul" = 4L,
                   "Centro-Oeste" = 5L)[Região] ]
```

### Unir as duas tabelas:

```r
tb3 = tb2[tb, on = c(UF = "SG_UF_PROVA")] # usando as colunas "SG_UF_PROVA" da tabela "tb" e "UF" da tabela "tb2" (ambas contem o dado da UF)
```

Resultado:

```r
> head(tb3)
   UF              Estado   Região Região2
1: PA                Pará    Norte       1
2: RN Rio Grande do Norte Nordeste       2
3: BA               Bahia Nordeste       2
4: SP           São Paulo  Sudeste       3
5: MG        Minas Gerais  Sudeste       3
6: RS   Rio Grande do Sul      Sul       4
>
```

Tabelas usadas no exemplo:

```r
> dput(tb)
structure(list(SG_UF_PROVA = c("PA", "RN", "BA", "SP", "MG", 
"RS", "PE", "SP", "PB", "CE")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

> dput(tb2)
structure(list(UF = c("RO", "AC", "AM", "RR", "PA", "AP", "TO", 
"MA", "PI", "CE", "RN", "PB", "PE", "AL", "SE", "BA", "MG", "ES", 
"RJ", "SP", "PR", "SC", "RS", "MS", "MT", "GO", "DF"), Estado = c("Rondônia", 
"Acre", "Amazonas", "Roraima", "Pará", "Amapá", "Tocantins", 
"Maranhão", "Piauí", "Ceará", "Rio Grande do Norte", "Paraíba", 
"Pernambuco", "Alagoas", "Sergipe", "Bahia", "Minas Gerais", 
"Espírito Santo", "Rio de Janeiro", "São Paulo", "Paraná", 
"Santa Catarina", "Rio Grande do Sul", "Mato Grosso do Sul", 
"Mato Grosso", "Goiás", "Distrito Federal"), Região = c("Norte", 
"Norte", "Norte", "Norte", "Norte", "Norte", "Norte", "Nordeste", 
"Nordeste", "Nordeste", "Nordeste", "Nordeste", "Nordeste", "Nordeste", 
"Nordeste", "Nordeste", "Sudeste", "Sudeste", "Sudeste", "Sudeste", 
"Sul", "Sul", "Sul", "Centro-Oeste", "Centro-Oeste", "Centro-Oeste", 
"Centro-Oeste"), Região2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                 "data.frame"))
```